# Need advice on how to print a matrix in lisp

Tags: opencv, printing, lisp, common-lisp, cffi

I have a matrix defined so if I do this

```
(format t "~a" (get-real-2d 0 0))
```

it prints out the element in the first row first column

and if I do this

```
(format t "~a" (get-real-2d a 0 1))
```

it prints out the element in first row second column

and if I do this

```
(format t "~a" (get-real-2d a 1 0))
```

it prints out the element in second row first column.

The matrix `a` looks like this

```
a =
((0 1 2)
(3 4 5)
(6 7 8))
```

and I was hoping you can show me exactly how to write a `dotimes` loop or other loop 
that would in as few lines as possible would print out the matrix using the `get-real-2d` function so the output looks  like this:

```
0 1 2 
3 4 5
6 7 8
```

I'm just hoping you can show me a slick loop that would be real small that I can use to print matrices that I can use in my lisp library something real professional looking, like one that would use only variables. Something like:

```
(format t "~a" (get-real-2d i j))
```

instead of a bunch of:

```
(format t "~a" (get-real-2d 0 0))
(format t "~a" (get-real-2d 0 1))
(format t "~a" (get-real-2d 0 2))
```

;;;;LATEST EDIT;;;
to make this simple I call

```
(defparameter a (create-mat 3 3 +32fc1+))
```

to create a 3x3 matrix - create-mat is a wrapper for opencv's cvCreateMat

the output from that command at repl is

```
(defparameter a (create-mat 3 3 +32fc1+))
A
CL-OPENCV> a
#.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X7FFFD8000E00)
```

i/e the variable a is a pointer to the 3x3 matrix

then I run

```
(defparameter data (cffi:foreign-alloc :float :initial-contents 
          '(0.0f0 1.0f0 2.0f0 3.0f0 4.0f0 5.0f0 6.0f0 7.0f0 8.0f0)))
```

to create the data for the matrix - which I next will allocate to the matrix

the output from that command at repl is

```
CL-OPENCV> (defparameter data (cffi:foreign-alloc :float :initial-contents 
          '(0.0f0 1.0f0 2.0f0 3.0f0 4.0f0 5.0f0 6.0f0 7.0f0 8.0f0)))
DATA
CL-OPENCV> data
#.(SB-SYS:INT-SAP #X7FFFD8000E40)
```

i/e the variable a is data pointer to the data ill add to the matrix

then I call..

```
(set-data a data 12) to add the data to the matrix - set-data is a wrapper for opencv's cvSetData
```

so now when I run - (get-real-2d is a wrapper for opencv's cvGetReal2d)

```
(get-real-2d a 0 0)  it gets the element of matrix a at row 0 col 0 which is 0.0d0
```

the output from that command at repl is

```
CL-OPENCV> (get-real-2d a 0 0)
0.0d0
```

and now when I run

```
(get-real-2d a 0 1)  it gets the element of matrix a at row 0 col 1 which is is 0.0d0
```

the output from that command at repl is

```
CL-OPENCV> (get-real-2d a 0 1)
1.0d0
```

and when I run this loop

```
 (dotimes (i 3)
  (dotimes (j 3)
(format t "~a~%" (get-real-2d a i j))))
```

the output from that command at repl is

```
CL-OPENCV> (dotimes (i 3)
  (dotimes (j 3)
(format t "~a~%" (get-real-2d a i j))))
0.0d0
1.0d0
2.0d0
3.0d0
4.0d0
5.0d0
6.0d0
7.0d0
8.0d0
NIL
```

but when I try your method @Svante

```
(dotimes (i 3)
  (dotimes (j 3)
(format t "~{~{~a~^ ~}~%~}" (get-real-2d a i j))))
```

I get error:

```
The value 0.0d0 is not of type LIST.
    [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]
```

because the output  of 1 run of get-real-2d is just a 1 number float i/e

```
CL-OPENCV> (get-real-2d a 0 0)
0.0d0
```

with that info can you help me print the matrix so it looks like this

```
0.0d0 1.0d0 2.0d0 
3.0d0 4.0d0 5.0d0
6.0d0 7.0d0 8.0d0
```

Comment: Why define matrix as a list? Array is a lot better for this purpose. There are a handful of libraries that provide some implementation of matrix and functions you may need to apply to it. Why not just use those? If your matrix is a list, then something like this: `(format t "~{~{~s~^ ~}~^~%~}" matrix)` should do the job, but really, consider first two earlier questions.

Comment: @wvxvw could you please look at my "Latest Edit" to my question

Comment: Well, you should've told what the format of the matrix is. You printed it as if it was a tree (a list containing other lists) when it is in fact a foreign object, most likely an array, but maybe a struct (I don't know how matrix is defined in OpenCV). Now, if you are after a long-term solution, I'd look into `cffi:defcstruct` and use its machinery to define a `print-object` method to print matrices. Else - I'd just have a function that prints the contents of the matrix to a stream, and then use it like here: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_ced.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be understood in two ways, and that is why it has two solutions:

- Define method for printing object of type matrix (in this case it may use the knowledge about the internal structure of matrix):

  ```
  (defmethod print-object ((matrix matrix) stream)
      (format stream "~{~{~a~^ ~}~%~}" matrix))
  ```

  Using `format` as is shown in the answers.
- Define client function that can use the only method of your object - `get-real-2d`:

  ```
  (defun print-matrix (matrix dimension-x dimension-y)
      (dotimes (x dimension-x)
          (dotimes (y dimension-y)
              (princ (get-real-2d matrix x y))
              (princ #\Space))
          (princ #\Newline)))
  ```

  Just using `dotimes`.

Comment: YOU NAILED IT!!! PERFECT PERFECT PEFECT...THAT WAS A GREAT ANSWER Thank you very much Menschenkindlein you helped me out alot! = )

Comment: @user2735131, if this is the perfect answer, how about voting it up and marking it as the official answer so that Menschenkindlein can get credit.

Answer (score 5):

You can do that directly in the `format` directive.  The format instructions `~{` and `~}` descend into a list structure.

```
(format t "~{~{~a~^ ~}~%~}" matrix)
```

The outer pair of `~{` `~}` loops over the first level of the matrix, so that the directives inside get to see one row at a time.  The inner pair of `~{` `~}` loops over each such row, so that the directives inside get to see one element at a time.  `~A` prints that element.  The part between `~^` and `~}` gets printed only between executions of the loop body, not at the end.  `~%` emits a `#\Newline`.

*EDIT as requested*

Note that the `~{` `~}` replace the looping, and that I named the variable `matrix`, not `element`.  You need to put the entire matrix there, and it is supposed to be in the form of a nested list.  I deduced this from your statement that `a` is `((0 1 2) (3 4 5) (6 7 8))`.  So, `(format t "~{~{~a~^ ~}~%~}" a)`.

If the matrix happens not to be in the form of a nested list but rather some kind of array, you really need to loop over the indices.  Nested `dotimes` forms should be sufficient at first:

```
(fresh-line)
(dotimes (i (array-dimension array 0))
  (dotimes (j (array-dimension array 1))
    (format t "~a " (aref array i j)))
  (terpri))
```

I don't know how your matrices map to arrays, so you will have to replace `array-dimension` and `aref` with your versions.

Comment: could you please look at my "Latest Edit" to my question

Answer (score 1):

This isn't hard, so I'd rather leave it to you to figure out, but here are some tips to make a "slick loop" Lisp-style.  I would suggest one or more instances of `mapc` (or `mapcar`), rather than `dotimes`.  This may feel odd if you're not used to functional programming, but once you're used to it, it's easier to read than `dotimes`, and you don't have to keep track of the indexes, so it can avoid errors.  You really should learn to use `mapcar/mapc` if you aren't already familiar with them.  They are cool.  Or if you want to be really cool :-) you could use recursion to iterate over the matrix, but I think that for this purpose iterating using `mapc` will be easier to read. (But you should learn the recursive way for other jobs.  If you find recursion confusing--I have no reason to think you do, but some people have trouble with it--my favorite tutorial is *The Little Schemer*.)

You may also want to use other `format` directives that allow you pad numbers with spaces if they don't have enough digits.  The `~%` directive may be useful as well.  Peter Seibel has a very nice [introduction to format](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/a-few-format-recipes.html).

Comment: still could use some sample code... been reading mapcar literature but no  ideas so far

Comment: I would actually give the opposite advice: if you don't already have a function defined that does exactly what you need, you would need to use `lambda` with `mapc` or `mapcar`. In those cases, using one of `dotimes`, `dolist`, or `loop` is usually more concise and readable (`dolist` or `loop in ... do ...` are exactly like `mapc`, `loop in ... collect ...` is just like `mapcar`.)

Comment: And explicit recursion should only be done if it can't be avoided, i.e. if the task at hand is not an iterative process. It's a low-level tool like `goto`.

Comment: @Mars could you please look at my "Latest Edit" to my question

Comment: @Rörd  could you please look at my "Latest Edit" to my question

Comment: Oops--when I mentioned the ugliness of `dotimes` (now edited out), I had in mind `do`.  Sorry about that.  It was late at night.

Answer (score 1):

Here are just the two `dotimes` loops that you were asking for. The only thing that you need to pay attention for is when to print spaces and when to print newlines.

```
(dotimes (i 3)
  (dotimes (j 3)
    (princ (get-real-2d a i j))
    (if (< j 2)
      (princ #\Space)
      (terpri))))
```

Alternatively, you might want to use the `format` directives for floating point printing to have the numbers always aligned in nice columns. You can choose between `~F` that will never print an exponent, `~E` that will always print one, and `~G` that behaves according to the magnitude. Look for details here in the HyperSpec: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cc.htm.

Here's an example that uses `~F` with a maximum field width of 5 and 1 fractional digit:

```
(dotimes (i 3)
  (dotimes (j 3)
    (format t "~5,1F" (get-real-2d a i j)))
  (terpri))
```